# jQuery ui, passing parameters to another function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css, jquery-ui

this one should be simple ,

in this  *JsFiddle*  (the link below, it's my first JsFiddle setup , great tool!),

I am trying to implement a new `jQuery ui`  :  `draggable`, `droppable` and `sortable` list , so this gui will be the setup of my new  **custom made** : Sql CRUD <sub>via Ajax</sub>  Capable - `GridView`

This fiddle shows the *first stage*,  where user selects a table to work with .

what I need to know is, ( i lack experience both `jquery` + `ui`)

... **how do I pass the results of chosen list items to next stage(new function) ?**

I'll be happy if someone with free time could help on this **thanks.**

Link1 : ***project-result*** - [JQuery Ui](http://jsfiddle.net/rhW7C/46/embedded/result/)

Link2 : ***Fiddle*** - http://jsfiddle.net/rhW7C/46/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of keeping those in a hidden field, you can keep add in some Javascript object array. That could be passed as a parameter.

Ex:

```
 var omittedItems=[];
 //check if the object already exists if not push
 omittedItems.push('yourobject');
```

Comment: hey , i thought of it nice one , could you please give some broader code example , or add one more step so i could connect it in my code and continue with that logic .